# Installing tum_ardrone with catkin_make

Tags: ros, rosdep-install, tum-ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ROS and having trouble setting up tum_ardrone for use with the Parrot Drone Quadcopter. I've installed ROS Hyrdro on Ubuntu version 12.04 and followed all the beginner tutorials with no problems. I've installed the pre-requites but when I try to install the tum_ardrone package as told to on their wiki by running, I get problems when running the following line:

```
rosdep install tum_ardrone
```

It spits out the the following error.

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource tum_ardrone
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

The link to the wiki with install instructions is here: [link text](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone)
The instructions extract is below.

```
cd catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone.git -b hydro-devel
cd ..
rosdep install tum_ardrone
catkin_make
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jonathan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190476/installing-tum_ardrone-with-catkin_make/) by [achery323](https://answers.ros.org/users/20035/achery323/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2014-08-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-19**:
I think the setup instructions assume that you've sourced the workspace before you begin.

**Comment by [achery323](https://answers.ros.org/users/20035/achery323/) on 2014-08-19**:
Thanks for the help, that fixed the ROS path errors, however it still can't find the resource tum_ardrone when running the line below. Do I have to manually tell rosdep where that folder is or something if it can't find it?

```
rosdep install tum_ardrone
```

From the tutorials I have seen using catkin_make though, they never use rosdep. They just git clone the link, go to the catkin_ws directory and then catkin_make. I've also tried this however the make fails as well.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-19**:
From your catkin_ws directory, you may want to try: `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src` instead.

**Comment by [achery323](https://answers.ros.org/users/20035/achery323/) on 2014-08-21**:
Okay, finally got it working so apologies for the late reply, I will post a solution to my question below in case other beginners have the same problem. Is there a way to not have to source the workspace every time I fire up my computer though?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-21**:
You can edit your shell's startup script, (usually ~/.bashrc) to include the source command so that you don't have to type it by hand each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anyone else if having this same problem, I had two issues:

1. Sourcing the workspace: running the following line before attempting the instructions worked for me and got rid of the missing rospath errors.
   source ~/catkin-ws/devel/setup.bash
2. Running rosdep update after the git clone command - rosdep needed to be update of the package just downloaded into the folder to recognise it was there.

A big thanks to ahendrix to helping with this! Definitely got the ball rolling in the right direction!

---

Originally posted by [achery323](https://answers.ros.org/users/20035/achery323/) with karma: 46 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1